# Cover with unit test WebRequest c#

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, design-patterns

```
public void HandleRequest(WebhookModel model)
{
        var strRequest = "cmd=_notify-validate&" + ipnContext.RequestBody;
        var webRequest = FormRequest(strRequest);
        var requestStream = _webRequestWrapper.GetRequestStream();
        var responseStream = _webRequestWrapper.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                model.Verification = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

}

private WebRequest FormRequest(string strRequest)
        {
            var webRequest = WebRequest.Create("some url is over here");

            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webRequest.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

            return webRequest;
        }
```

Where `_webrequestWrapper` just a wrapper around `WebRequest` class. 
So, my question is how I can mock `_webRequestWrapper.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()` ? The problem is that there is no problems with mocking `GetResponse()` because of we create  for it wrapper around `WebRequest`, but the problem is with GetReponseStream, because it returns a Stream object, how I can test `HandleRequest()` method?
I really have not any ideas about it. Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to test? It just appears that you are reading the response stream, which isn't worth testing IMO. If you have more logic that you have excluded, break that out into a separate method and write tests for it.

Comment: I just want to test HandleRequest() but i'm not sure whether it worth testing. Could you explaim why it's not needed to be tested?

Comment: I'd agree you shouldn't bother testing the response stream reads; it's an external dependency to your app. If you did need to test it, using a shim would probably be the best approach. [See this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx).

Comment: The only thing *your* code is doing is `model.Verification = reader.ReadToEnd();`, so you'd be testing whether you can set a property on an object. I'm pretty sure that's going to work in most cases. Any issues that you encounter with `WebRequest` and its friends should probably be handled using `try/catch` blocks.

Comment: Completely agree with you. Thank for help. Could you add is as answer so that i can upvote you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything worth testing in `HandleRequest(WebhookModel model)`.

The only thing your code is doing is `model.Verification = reader.ReadToEnd();`, so you'd be testing whether you can set a property on an object. I'm pretty sure that's going to work in most cases.

Any issues that you encounter with `WebRequest` and related I/O classes should probably be handled using try/catch blocks.

Unit tests are good for business logic or general assumptions about inputs and outputs, and should be fairly easy to create and maintain. If you find yourself spending lots of time mocking I/O classes, then consider whether you can break out testable units of work into separate (preferably static) methods. You'll make your life and coworkers' lives easier.